# Install Postgre SQL in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: pi-3, software-installation, database

Anoyone try to install postgresql in Raspbian Stretch?
I follow the instructions to the postgresql'site, but when in type sudo apt-get update, returns the follow error:

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt strech-pgdg InReleas' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'

I read the other post here about installation in Raspian-Jessie. Is the same thing?

Comment: It's implicit here you've added a repo, probably one intended for x86(-64) users.  There is no need to do that (and it could never work anyway).  PostgreSQL [is available in stock Raspbian](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/) -- looks like *six different versions, in fact,* up to 10.1.  Undo whatever you did to the repo sources list and `apt search postgresql`, go from there.

Answer (score 5):

As of right now (11/24/2017) you can install Postgresql v9.6 (stable/armhf) directly from the default Raspbian repositories via this command in the terminal/shell:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-9.6
```

If you need a newer version (10.1, etc.) then you may have to compile from the source.  Painful, but doable...

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I've built `armhf` binaries for Raspbian stretch for PostgreSQL 11.2 that you can use by adding the apt repo:

```
deb https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/james-coleman/postgresql-arm-debian/deb/raspbian stretch main
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out the latest version of PostgreSQL (that you can install with apt):

```
sudo apt-cache search postgresql | less
```

As of now (12/14/2017) latest version (from the default Raspbian Stretch apt repo; not Jessie or Wheezy) is still postgresql-9.6, but the good news is that there are a lot of extension packages for this version.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you can install PostgreSQL by using:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql-9.6
```

**However** I would not recommend using PgSQL on RPi unless:

- your RPi is on battery / UPS or
- you will put DB on an external hard drive.

It depends on frequency of writing to DB, but I've had 2 failures in last 2 months connected to power failures. One rendered SD card broken and the other corrupted data in PostgreSQL enough to make it unusable. In my case I had backups, but it still makes the solution very unreliable.

Note that the power failures were not frequent - one was caused by the storm while the other... just happened. There might have been others in between, but not many.